# creating a list using a function from an undefined list

Tags: python, function

I'm asked to create a list of numbers that stops when the number 7 appears.

I've tried the following, but get a runtime error:

```
def sublist(x):
    s = []
    while x != 7:
        s.append(x)
    return s
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where inside that function would the value of `x`, and therefore the result of its equality comparison with `7`, change?

Comment: `return list(itertools.filter(lambda y: y != 7, x))`? Is the argument to the function suppose to be a list (or at least iterable)?

Answer (score -1):

If you're getting a runtime error, you probably cannot compare the type of `x` to `7`. Try

```py
def sublist(x):
    s = []
    for elem in x:
        if elem != 7:
            s.append(elem)
        else:
            break
    return s
```

This will only work if x is iterable and has elements that can be compared to `7`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
def sublist(x):
    s = []
    x1=0 #initialized x1
    while x[x1] != 7:
        s.append(x[x1])
        if x1==len(x)-1:
            break
        x1+=1 #increment x1
    return s

x=[1,4,8,9,2,7,4,2,3,4]
print(sublist(x))
```

output:

```
[1, 4, 8, 9, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4]
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you, but the list doesn't iterate. It's an undefined list that might include any number.

Comment: is the x you are passing to function is a list

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really stuck.